# How to initialize an ArrayList with lombok @Builder and @Data

Tags: java, arraylist, lombok

Using lombok for a project, I have an ArrayList.  It's null because it's never initialized.  I originally initialized this in the constructor before I decided to use lombok to remove the bulk of boilerplate code.

What's the simplest example of getting it to work?

Example : Calling refresh throws a null pointer after creating a builder (Note: I've omitted variables that are used in the builder, but `parameters` is not mentioned in the builder so perhaps I need to do something with it).

```
@Builder
public @Data class RMF_Objective {

   private ArrayList<String> parameters;

   public void refresh(){     
        parameters.clear(); // Clear for now
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest initializing it with the Lombok's builder is like this:

```
    @Builder
    public @Data class RMF_Objective {

        private ArrayList<String> parameters;

        public void refresh() {
            parameters.clear(); // Clear for now
            System.out.println("cleared !");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two"));
            RMF_Objective builtObject = new RMF_ObjectiveBuilder()
                    .parameters(list)
                    .build();
            builtObject.refresh();
        }
    }
```

Otherwise you could also use Lombok's @Singular annotation to make it generate a 'singular' version of the parameters() method taking only one String as input parameter. Like this:

```
@Builder
public @Data class RMF_ObjectiveSingular {

    @Singular
    private List<String> parameters;

    public void refresh() {
        parameters.clear(); // Clear for now
        System.out.println("cleared !");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two"));
        RMF_ObjectiveSingular builtObject = new RMF_ObjectiveSingularBuilder()
                .parameter("one")
                .parameter("two")
                .build();
        builtObject.refresh();
    }
}
```

But if I were you, I would really use only the @Value's Lombok annotation. If you don't need a builder, it's simpler to have only a constructor initializing the object and Getter but no Setters. Immutables objects are often safer.

Comment: I think you meant it's safer to have only Getter and no Setters

Comment: Didn't know about @Singular, fixed an issue i had deploying a pojo.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://reinhard.codes/2016/07/13/using-lomboks-builder-annotation-with-default-values/ using default values in your class won't work.

You can provide a minimal builder implementation containing the default values like:

```
public static class RMF_ObjectiveBuilder{
    private ArrayList<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If annotated with `@Builder.Default`, `parameters` is initialised:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class RMF_Objective {

  @Builder.Default private ArrayList<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

  public void refresh(){
    parameters.clear(); // Clear for now
  }

}
```

From the [documentation](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder):

> @Builder.Default
>
> If a certain field/parameter is never set during a build session, then it always gets 0 / null / false. If you've put @Builder on a class (and not a method or constructor) you can instead specify the default directly on the field, and annotate the field with @Builder.Default: @Builder.Default private final long created = System.currentTimeMillis();

Note that:

- `@Data` - which includes `@RequiredArgsConstructor` - has been removed
- `@AllArgsConstructor` - included in `@Builder` - access level has been set to `PRIVATE` (default is `PUBLIC`)

This prevents instantiating `RMF_Objective` via its one-argument constructor such as

```
new RMF_Objective(null).refresh()
```

which would throw `NullPointerException`.