# Initialize a List<Players> inside the class Team

Tags: java, spring, list

When I manage to recall the contructor from the Teams class (which store the `List<Players>` in it) is obvs `null`. Where do I populate that List? Do I need to populate it inside the Players class? Or inside the Team class?

I am working with Spring recently.

I'll leave the examples of the 3 class. Squadre means Teams, Giocatori means Players.
(using lombok)

```java
    public class Squadra {
    
        private String nomeSquadra;
    
        private List<Giocatori> rosaAttuale;
        private int goalFatti;
        private int goalSubiti;
        private int differenzaReti;
        private int posizioneInCampionato;
        private double valoreRosa;
    
        public void addGiocatori(Giocatori g) {
            rosaAttuale.add(g);
        }
    
        public void removeGiocatori(Giocatori g) {
            rosaAttuale.remove(g);
        }
    
    }


    public class Giocatori {
    
        String nomeGiocatore;
        String cognomeGiocatore;
        int eta;
        int numeroMaglia;
    
        public Giocatori() {
    
        }
    
    }

    @Component
    public class SquadreRepo {
    
        @Getter
        private List<Squadra> dataBaseSquadre = new ArrayList<Squadra>();
    
        public SquadreRepo() {
    
            dataBaseSquadre.add(new Squadra(null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
            
        }
    
        public void addSquadra(Squadra s) {
            dataBaseSquadre.add(s);
        }
    
        public void removeSquadra(Squadra s) {
            dataBaseSquadre.remove(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using  `dataBaseSquadre.add(new Squadra(null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))`
I dont see any constructor of such signature in Squadra. Is that present in your code ?

Comment: I am using Lombok, with @AllArgsConstr, that's why you can't see it here. Tried to post it but it wouldn't show up!

Answer (score 1):

Your list of players **rosaAttuale** of class **Squadra** is never initialized in the code above. You initialize your team in **SquadreRepo** by calling the constructor with

```
dataBaseSquadre.add(new Squadra(null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

The second parameter is presumably the **rosaAttuale** list (assuming the constructor was generated using Lombok), so your list is **null** and you can never add any players. Instead, try to initialize it with an empty list, e.g.:

```
dataBaseSquadre.add(new Squadra(null, new ArrayList<>(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Also see these questions for properly initializing collections when using Lombok builders:

- [Lombok @Builder not initializing collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824821/lombok-builder-not-initializing-collections)
- [How to initialize an ArrayList with lombok @Builder and @Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379012/how-to-initialize-an-arraylist-with-lombok-builder-and-data)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very clear but I understand that you get a `NullPointerException` when you run this method:

```
public void addGiocatori(Giocatori g) {
    rosaAttuale.add(g); //<- rosaAttuale is null
}
```

If that's what you mean, indeed, you need to initialize the list when you build the class `Squadra`.

To do that, there are at least two options:

*Either in the constructor*:

```
 public Squadra() {
     this.rosaAttuale = new ArrayList<>();
 }
```

*Or in the field declaration directly*:

```
private final List<Giocatori> rosaAttuale = new ArrayList<>();
```